# open popup view from event click with slideoverkit on xamarin studio pcl

Tags: c#, xaml, popup, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

I'm trying to follow the guide to enter the popup from [slideoverkit](http://www.xam-consulting.com/slideoverkit-xamarin-forms/) plugin, but I can not find the instructions to open the popup.
That said here is my code:

Popup XAML View xamarin forms pcl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:t="clr-namespace:SlideOverKit"
             x:Class="Fimap.Popup.MachinePinDetail">
  <StackLayout Padding="15,10,15,30" Spacing="20" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <Label HeightRequest="30" Text="Build some Awesome SlideOver's" FontSize="24" XAlign="Center" />
    <Entry Placeholder="Testing..." HeightRequest="40"/>
    <Image HeightRequest="40" Source="xamconsulting.png">
    </Image>
    <Button x:Name="DoneButton" Text="Close" />
  </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

CodeBehind Popup Xaml view:

```
using SlideOverKit;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Fimap.Popup
{
    public partial class MachinePopupView : SlidePopupView
    {
        public MachinePopupView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.BackgroundColor = Color.Red;

            // If you set Target attached property, you should not set TopMargin and LeftMargin
            // But you need to set Width and Height request
            this.WidthRequest = 200;
            this.HeightRequest = 300;

            DoneButton.Clicked += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
                this.HideMySelf();
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Another xaml view have this event:

```
private void Pin_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //qui raccolgo il pin selezionato e visualizzo il popup view della macchina
            var pin = sender as Pin;
            var serialNumberFimap = Regex.Match(pin.Address, @"\d+").Value;          
            //here open popup view with slide over kit
        }
```

When I click the current view event this latter, I would like to open the view pop-up with slideoverkit, but that instructions have to perform to ensure that it opens? thank you